# git exclude specific folder and it's content from gitignore rule

Tags: git

I have a .gitignore file within my project with the following rules:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
[Xx]64/
[Xx]86/
[Bb]uild/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

I have a specific folder in my application that uses the keyword "Build" but I want to include this particular folder and it's files as part of my commits.

The paths I want to include are as following:

```
Views/Build/Index.cshtml
Views/Build/Create.cshtml
```

I've tried the following but it isn't working:

```
!Views/[Bb]uild/*
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm struggling to find an answer to my problem and hope someone can help.

Comment: Btw. you can prefix your ignore rules with `/` to make the apply at the root, e.g. when build output is only ever built into the root folder.

Comment: Btw. (2), Git will only ignore files that aren’t already tracked by Git, so you can always explicitely add files using `git add -f Views/Build/Index.cshtml` even if that file is actually ignored (this will effectively turn off the ignore rule for that file, so subsequent changes will also be detected properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!Views/[Bb]uild` to your .gitignore file at the bottom (after the other rules). I've tested this with the following file:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
[Xx]64/
[Xx]86/
[Bb]uild/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

!Views/[Bb]uild
```

The difference between your attempt and mine was that you added `!Views/[Bb]uild/*` and I added `!Views/[Bb]uild`.

I believe the reason that `!Views/[Bb]uild/*` doesn't work is because it's saying "exclude all contents underneath 'Views/Build' from being ignored", but this by itself has no effect as the directory itself is still ignored. My rule excludes the directory itself (and by extension everything under it).

**Edit**

This is the tree structure of the directory I've tested this in:

```
$ tree -a -I .git
.
├── .gitignore
├── hello.cs
├── temp.py
├── temp.txt
├── temp.vi
└── Views
    └── Build
        ├── Create.cshtml
        └── Index.cshtml
```

This is the output from `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitignore
        Views/
        hello.cs
        temp.py
        temp.txt
        temp.vi
```

Comment: I've tried as you suggested and still no joy. After running git check-ignore, the global rule still seems to be applied:
`$ git check-ignore -v XXX/Views/Build/Status.cshtml
.gitignore:20:[Bb]uild/ XXX/Views/Build/Status.cshtml`

Comment: @jgill09 I get that output from git check-ignore too, but if you try unstaging and restaging all changes you should see it work (`git reset && git add -A && git status`)

Comment: Perfect, that's worked. Thank you.

Comment: @jgill09 Great. If it solves your problem, I'd appreciate if you'd accept the answer. :)